# linux malloc: when pages are actually mapped?

Tags: c, linux, malloc

If there is no memory `malloc` calls `brk`. Pages are mapped by kernel if user writes data to it.
But `malloc` maintain lists of chunks of various size.
https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals
What memory does `malloc` use for meta chunk data? If `malloc` uses the memory from `brk` call, pages are already mapped before user writes to them.

Comment: See the "Arenas and Heaps" section of the documentation you linked to. The metadata is at the beginning of the heap, and they're in a linked list, so it can use the beginning of the memory it just allocated with `sbrk`.

Comment: "pages are already mapped before user writes to them."  Sure.  Why should that be a problem?

Comment: Basically, if the user cares at all about when pages are actually resident, they should be using `mmap`, `madvise`, `mlock` and such.  `malloc` just isn't designed to provide that kind of control.

Comment: "Why should that be a problem? " - its not a problem. I would like to sort out, how malloc works. It seems to me malloc should write meta chunk data before user to those pages

Comment: `What memory does malloc use for meta chunk data?` is an excellent question. It is also irrelevant. Malloc somehow manages to record the information that it needs to operate correctly. That information is not visible to you. What is visible, is that malloc behaves as documented. (or not).